# Get the name of variable from a JSON file in GitHub Actions

Tags: json, azure-devops, github-actions

I am trying to setup the GitHub actions for deployment to the Azure. What I am trying to do is getting the name of some variables from the armtemplates with the given code.

```
name: Create Initial Resources

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - CreateResources

jobs:

  Read:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Chekout branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: CreateResources
      
      - name: get storage account
        run: |
              echo ::set-output name=storage-account-name::$(jq '.parameters.storage_account_name.value' at ./armtemplates/sac/parameters-example.json)
```

This is the code that I use, first it checks the branch and in the second step it tries to parse the file that is in the branch but the error is like this:

```
jq: error: Could not open file at: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Before `echo ::set-output` please add `ls .` to see what you have in directory.

Comment: I run it and I can see that it is inside branch because I can see the armtemplates folder with README.md. I started to think it could be related to jg part of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue here is `at` phrase. Please use this:

```sh
echo ::set-output name=storage-account-name::$(jq '.parameters.storage_account_name.value' ./armtemplates/sac/parameters-example.json)
```